# Stop text from displaying inline

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

My text is displaying inline and I don't want it to.

Why does this code cause it to display inline?

```
<Card style={{

  marginBottom: 10,
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: 'green'
}}>
  <CardItem style={{


    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'red',

    alignItems: 'center'
  }}>
    <Text style={{
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      marginBottom: 15,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    }}>
      {this.selectedProduct.name}
    </Text>
    <Text style={{
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      marginBottom: 15,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      width: '100%'
    }}>
      {this.selectedProduct.description}
    </Text>
    <Text style={{
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      marginBottom: 15,
      width: '100%'
    }}>
      price: {this.selectedProduct.price ? this.selectedProduct.price + ' of your local currency' : 'not entered'}
    </Text>
  </CardItem>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `flexDirection: 'row'`, if you want to display it in column, just use `flexDirection: 'column'`, like this:

```
<Card style={{

  marginBottom: 10,
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  backgroundColor: 'green'
}}>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean "in ONE line"? That due to using `flex` in there - it treats all child elements as flex items (also plain text) and distributes them accordingly across one line. You can change `flexDirection` to 'column' to place the texts *above* each other.